# The loop does not work after the first passage of the element

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

For some reason, the usual for loop in my situation doesn't work for me. After completing one cycle, the cycle ends. I created a method in my controller that takes an id from an object and writes it to a List< int >

```dart
final productIdList = <Price>[].obs; 
final productIntIdList = <int>[].obs;

void convertId() {
    print("${productIdList.length}");
     for (int i = 0; i < productIdList.length; i ++){
      productIntIdList.value[i] = productIdList[i].ProductId!;
    }
  }
```

And the method that precedes this method:

```dart
Future getPriceList() async{
    productIdList.value = await priceType.value.getPrices(columnsToSelect: [PriceFields.ProductId.toString()])!.toList();
    convertId();
  }
```

Edit1:

This is the error I get:
[image: Error]

Comment: are you using `getx`?

Comment: Yes, I use getX

Answer (score 0):

I understood why this happened. I tried to access the index of an array that does not exist.

It is enough to change what was on it:

```dart
for (int i = 0; i < productIdList.length; i++){
      productIntIdList.add(productIdList[i].ProductId!);
    }
```